# Требуется ли здесь запятая перед КАК?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Узнать **как** передвигаются молекулы в воде.
Они знают **как** сделать домашнее задание.
Отпишусь о результатах **как** сдам.

ПОЧЕМУ?

Answer (score 1):

Каждое из указанных предложений является сложносочинённым,
и простые предложения, составляющие его, должны быть разделены запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая требуется во всех трёх примерах.

Если после "как" стоит глагол - сказуемое, то это начало придаточного предложения в **сложноподчинённом** предложении (не сложносочинённом - как сказано в другом ответе).

В первых двух примерах союз "как" изъяснительный.
В третьем - временной.
Классификация союзов здесь: https://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=souz_kak_chast_rechi

Запятая не ставится, если после "как" (или другого подчинённого союза) ничего нет:
*Не знаю как.

Не могу объяснить почему.

Учащимся назначили экзамен, но не уточнили когда.

Со стороны проспекта кто-то шёл — издали было неясно кто.*